# Reactive Extensions - Flushing Subject / IObservable in a synchronous fashion

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

EDIT: I've edited a few lines of code, when running in the IDE it fails without an error or anything.

I'm new to Reactive Extensions and have a problem that I am trying to sort out.  I'm using RX to queue events on a machine, then every so often send that data to a server.  My problem appears to be that when the application is shutting down, anything that is an async call of any sort seems to just cancel and not run, thus the last batch of events never gets sent.

I have a Subject, where Event is my data class.  I know now that a Subject might not be the best class to use, but here we are.

My code looks mostly like the following, added a few comments for clarity:

```
IObservable<IList<Event>> eventsObserver = Instance.EventBuffer.ToList<Event>();
var eventsEnumerable = eventsObserver.ToEnumerable();
List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
try
{
    events = (List<Event>)eventsEnumerable.First();  // THIS LINE FAILS SILENTLY, EVEN IN DEBUGGER...
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(someURI);
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(somePage, new StringContent(SerializeToJSON(events))).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

If I don't make the call to the web server synchronous (with the '.Result'), it fails there.  I've tried a lot of ways to get the data from the IObservable into something I can send, but either the code fails (usually with a bad cast of some sort), or the events are not yet put into the data structure that I want to send.  I know that RX is by nature async, and I'm asking to deal with it in a synchronous way, I would figure that there would be a solution.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The call to `eventsEnumerable.First()` only completes if the observable `Instance.EventBuffer` ends with `OnCompleted`. Does that happen? Can you provide a [mcve] to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you control the Observable source, you could call `Observable.OnComplete()` like Enigmativity has pointed out. Otherwise, you could try to keep a copy of every value received before buffering it:

```
Observable.Do(x => localCopy = x).Buffer(..)
```

This local copy would be accessible to you at shutdown.

In any case, please note that `.First()` is marked obsolete in the latest Rx versions, possibly to avoid the problem you are experiencing.